# Compiling node.js application to desktop app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to compile node.js my app into a desktop application. I am using Electron. When I try to run my application, an error occurs. (See screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Atom Shell is no longer supported by the Electron bindings.
Make your binary bindings fall back to compiling from source, this should Just Work.